# nested if else in javascript

Tags: javascript, nested

I have trouble with the nested if structure in javascript. Any help is appreciated.

```
function validateForm()
{
    var a = document.forms["demo1"]["addr1"].value;
    var b = document.forms["demo1"]["city"].value;
    //var c = document.forms["demo1"]["fname"].value;
    //var d = document.forms["demo1"]["lname"].value;
    //var f = document.forms["demo1"]["phno"].value;
    //var g = document.forms["demo1"]["email"].value;
    //var g1 = document.forms["demo1"]["cemail"].value;
    //var h = document.forms["demo1"]["pwd"].value;
    //var h1 = document.forms["demo1"]["cpwd"].value;
    if(b=="" || b==null)
    {
      alert("Please enter your city");
      return false;
      break;
    }
    else if(a=="" || a==null)
        {
            alert("Please enter your address");
            return false;
            break;
        }
    else {return true;} 
}

<form name = "demo1" action = "exp2.php" onsubmit = "return validateForm()" method = "POST">
```

The code works fine(as intended) if there is only one if statement. But I am not getting the intended result if more than one if else is been deployed.

Regards,
Mani

Comment: why there is a `break`

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EsJXu/

Answer (score 5):

First, you don't need `break` statements, they're useless in this context.

Second, you don't need to nest and, in fact, you *shouldn't* since checking of `a` and `b` is independent of each other:

```
if(b=="" || b==null)
{
    alert("Please enter your city");
    return false;
}

if(a=="" || a==null)
{
    alert("Please enter your address");
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about shorten ur code with reusable `isEmpty` function

```
function validateForm()
{

    var isEmpty = function ( name , label ){

          var val = document.forms["demo1"][ name ].value;

          if( ! val  )
          {
               alert("Please enter your "+ label );
               return true;     
          }

          return false;

    }         

    return !isEmpty( 'city', 'city') && 
           !isEmpty( 'addr1', 'address');

}
```

isEmpty return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Like paxdiablo says you can use two separate if statements.

But if you only want to require an address when a city is entered you must realize that this is not a nested if statement. This is:

```
if(b=="" || b==null)
{
  alert("Please enter your city");
  return false;
}
else 
{
    if(a=="" || a==null)
    {
        alert("Please enter your address");
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

A more reabable version would be, imo:

```
if(b=="" || b==null)
{
  alert("Please enter your city");
  return false;
}

if((b=="" || b == null) && (a=="" || a==null))
{
    alert("Please enter your address");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(b=="" || b==null) {
alert("Please enter your city");
return false;
}
else if(a=="" || a==null) {
alert("Please enter your address");
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
```